# NVIDIA 96 not working in Maverick

Tags: 10.10, xorg, kernel, nvidia

I recently upgraded to Maverick and X stopped working. I used to run NVIDIA-96, but now when I `modprobe nvidia` I'm getting the following error:

```
FATAL: Error inserting nvidia (/lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia.ko): No such device
```

Installing 96-series driver from nvidia.com yields the same result. I also tried to run on nouveau drivers, but it can only give me 640x480 resolution, which is not acceptable.

Graphics card details are:

```
# lspci -nn | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation NV18 [GeForce4 MX 440 AGP 8x] [10de:0181] (rev a2)
```

Is there any PPA with updated driver?

Comment: Even if its talking about Karmic, [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-96/+bug/476319) might be usefull, especially from the point of view of purging the Nvidia driver to make NV driver work. Your cards are the same.

Comment: Which way you've used while upgrading to Maverick? If it was a Web upgrade, try a fresh install. If it was a fresh install, install back Lucid, make it properly work with the driver of your choice and perform a Web upgrade. I'm gambling but it may work.

Answer (score 2):

Nvidia 96 drivers are not released for maverick (xorg 1.9) yet.
But work is in progress. It will be available soon.
http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showpost.php?p=2326233&postcount=5

For now, you can downgrade xorg to 1.7 or even downgrade to Lucid.

EDIT:
Now you can use 96 drivers!!!
http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?p=2341157

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dajhorn/nvidia-96
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-96
sudo nvidia-xconfig
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Add to Section "Device"

```
Option "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"
Option "DisableGLXRootClipping" "True"
```

reboot and profit!

Answer (score 0):

Seen [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1592628)?

I gave up some time ago on these old cards, replacing them with newer technology thanks to eBay.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fixed version of nvidia-96 (96.43.19) in the maverick-proposed repository.  I was able to fix my system (GeForce 4MX) by enabling the [proposed repository](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed) (including setting up "selective upgrading") and then running the command:

```
sudo aptitude -t maverick-proposed install nvidia-96 nvidia-96-modaliases
```

and then rebooting my machine.

Answer (score -1):

this is because you don't have this routine compiled for this kernel.

nvidia-glx-96 nvidia-96

nvidia-96-modaliases

nvidia-common

nvidia-96-kernel-source

.. Check this to completely uninstall.

> sudo aptitude purge
>   nvidia-glx-96 nvidia-96
>   nvidia-96-modaliases nvidia-common nvidia-96-kernel-source

then the follow :

> sudo apt-get install
>   nvidia-glx-96 nvidia-96
>   nvidia-96-modaliases nvidia-common nvidia-96-kernel-source

and in the final of this process, you can see this :

First Installation: checking all kernels...

Building only for 2.6.35-22-generic

Building initial module for 2.6.35-22-generic

Done.

**nvidia-96.ko:** at this point you now have the nvidia driver compiler for this kernel

Running module version sanity check.

- Original module

  - No original module exists within this kernel
- Installation

  - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod.......

DKMS: install Completed.

now you can go to System - Administration - Hardware Controler and you can see the new controler there and you can enable it...